# Error adding parameters to a PCF message with WebSphere MQ API

Tags: java, message, pcf

I am having trouble adding parameters to a specific PCF Message. I am trying to use `Inquire Log` (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzac.doc%2Fpc12720_.htm) and as you can see it only has one optional parameter. But when I look at the response list it shows that I should be able to get information such as `TotalLogs` or `LogUsed`.

What I am trying to do it:

```
PCFMessage inquireLogStatus = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_LOG);
inquireLogStatus.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQSYSP_TYPE_LOG_STATUS, CMQCFC.MQIACF_SYSP_FULL_LOGS);
```

Or something along those lines... any ideas? I keep getting:

```
3014 (0BC6): MQRCCF_CFIN_PARM_ID_ERROR
```

Thanks ahead of time for anything you can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

okay,I figured out what my problem was: here are a few pieces of my solution to guide anyone who needs this in the right direction:

```
pcfResponses = this.queryAgent.send (CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_LOG, null);
respStruct  = new MQCFH (pcfResponses [respCount]);
pcfParam = PCFParameter.nextParameter (pcfResponses [respCount]);
pcfParam.getParameter() == CMQCFC.MQCACF_DATA_SET_NAME);
```